# How to do CSS nth-child in span tags?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Apparently the nth-child pseudo is working well with tds or trs in a table. but what about span tags?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="refals_wr" style="font: normal 14px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; border-top: 2px dashed #CCC;">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <span>NAME OF SORTING ALGORITHM:</span><br />
                    <span id="algName">Bubble Sort</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <span>TOTAL SWAPS:</span><br />
                    <span id="algTotalSwaps">50</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <span>SWAP COUNT:</span><br />
                    <span id="algSwapCount">8</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#refals_wr span:nth-child(odd)  { color: green;  }
#refals_wr span:nth-child(even) { color: orange; }
```

Does not give desired result, everything is Green! Also, the last span (the one under SWAP COUNT containing the number "8") should **not** be affected in the coloring.

Is there a better way?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xzdv5csp/

Comment: Given this markup, the 1st child is `span`, the 2nd child is `br` and the last `span` is the 3rd child of each `div`. That explains the behavior. `nth-of-type`, as suggested by srekoble, accounts only elements of one type (i.e. `spans` here).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `nth-of-type`

```
#refals_wr span:nth-of-type(odd){
    color:green;}

#refals_wr span:nth-of-type(even){
    color:orange;}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/xzdv5csp/1/

Comment: Works well, how browser friendly is the `nth-type-of`?? any idea?

Comment: @UniversalGrasp you could check the support here http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Comment: The browser support is the same as for `nth-child`: http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-of-type

Comment: Could you help?... What if I want to Exclude the last child? any Idea?... I tried `#refals_wr #refals_wr span:nth-of-type(even):not(last-child)`, and `#refals_wr span:nth-of-type(even), #refals_wr span:not(:last-child)`.... NO desiring results... Pleasse help if ok, thanks

Comment: @UniversalGrasp what style do you want to give to last-child? You could always use `:last-of-type`

Comment: How to exclude the last child using the `last-type-of`?

Comment: @UniversalGrasp Check this example. The third-last span in 'sorting algorithms' is the `:last-of-type` and it's colored red (if you have only 1 span then they are all last-of-type so they are going to be all red) http://jsfiddle.net/xzdv5csp/8/

Comment: Sure... I want ONLY the number `8` under `SWAP COUNT` to be *Red colored*

Comment: @UniversalGrasp You could either use it's `id` since you gave it a specific name like `#algTotalSwaps { color: red }` or give a class name to the last td and use the last of type like this example: http://jsfiddle.net/xzdv5csp/9/

Answer (score 4):

`:nth-child` matches if the element is the specified child of its parent. The `<br>` element inside the div is causing the odd and even part of your selectors to fail since it makes both spans odd children (1st and 3rd) of its parent.

The following alternatives should work, even in lame browsers:

```css
#refals_wr span { color: green; }
#refals_wr span[id] { color: orange; }

/* Or */

#refals_wr span { color: orange; }
#refals_wr span:first-child { color: green; }
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/xzdv5csp/7/)

---

Now that you mention that the last span in last cell must be treated differently, there are couple of ways to do it but they all involve targeting or excluding the last `td` element. Here is one example that uses `:not()`:

```css
#refals_wr span { color: green; }
#refals_wr td:not(:last-child) span[id] { color: orange; }

/* Or */

#refals_wr2 span { color: green; }
#refals_wr2 td:not(:last-child) span:last-child { color: orange; }
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/xzdv5csp/10/)

If you want to avoid `:not()` due to browser support then you could use for example:

- `td:last-child`
- `td:first-child, td:first-child + td`

Answer (score 2):

**TRY** - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xzdv5csp/6/)**

```
#refals_wr span {
    color:orange;
}

#refals_wr span:nth-child(1) {
    color:green;
}
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/ and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: Using a formula (an + b). Description: a represents a cycle size, n is a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value.

Comment: `3n + 1` is not required. `:nth-child(1)` or `:first-child` should be enough to target the first child.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div:nth-child(even) span{
    color:orange;
}

div:nth-child() span{
    color:Green;
}
```